# Mostrar la primera imagen de un readdir en un bucle anidado

Tags: imagen, while

A ver si alguién me puede ayudar a verdonde estoy fallando.

Tengo una DB en Mysql, donde hay la tabla Producs con sus campos (id, name, descripion,...).
Para este proyecto se me ocuriió no usar campos con los links de las imagenes, que se suben a un directorio que se crea con el mismo nombre que el campo name. Así, pensé, no será dificil localizarlas con la ruta correcta, ya que no necesitaba en principio, cogerlas individualmente, siempre planeaba cogerlas en grupo (4)...

Todo funciona estupendamente bien, hasta que se me ocurrió coger una de esas imagenes para poner de pre-muestra en la consulta.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products"; 
        $link = conectarse();
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        
          while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            
            $dir="../../products/".$row['name']."/"; 

                    if ($directorio = opendir($dir)){
                    
                        while (false !== ($archivo = readdir($directorio))) {
                            if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
                                $foto= "<img width='150px' src='".$dir.$archivo."'>";
    
                                
                            }
                         
                        }
                        
                    }
            
            print ("<div ><div class='linia'>".$row['id']."</div> <div class='linia'>".$row['name']."</div><div class='linia'>".$row['description']."</div><div class='linia'>".$row['price']."</div>".$foto."</div>");
          }
```

Bueno, la cosa funciona bastante bien, siempre que me sirva de muestra la ultima foto de cada directorio... Peeeero y si quiero la primera imagen???

he probado

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products"; 
        $link = conectarse();
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        
          while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            
            $dir="../../products/".$row['name']."/"; 

                    if ($directorio = opendir($dir)){
                    
                        while (false !== ($archivo = readdir($directorio))) {
                            if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
                                $foto= "<img width='150px' src='".$dir.$archivo."'>";
                                                    print ("<div ><div class='linia'>".$row['id']."</div> <div class='linia'>".$row['name']."</div><div class='linia'>".$row['description']."</div><div class='linia'>".$row['price']."</div>".$foto."</div>");
                                
                            }
                         
                        }
                        
                    }
            
            
          }
```

Y claro, me imprime 1 linea completa por cada imagen..

probé

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products"; 
        $link = conectarse();
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        
          while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            
            $dir="../../products/".$row['name']."/"; 

                    if ($directorio = opendir($dir)){
                     $i==1;
                        while (false !== ($archivo = readdir($directorio))&&$i<1) {
                            if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
                                $foto= "<img width='150px' src='".$dir.$archivo."'>";
                                                    print ("<div ><div class='linia'>".$row['id']."</div> <div class='linia'>".$row['name']."</div><div class='linia'>".$row['description']."</div><div class='linia'>".$row['price']."</div>".$foto."</div>");
                                 $i++;
                            }
                         
                        }
                        
                    }
            
            
          }
```

con el contador $i, pero claro peta, al primer resultado... He probado tambien, haciendo de $foto quesea $foto[]... pero luego no consigo vincular eso al id de cada linea... he sacado los bucles anidados, y yo que se cuantas cosas...

Estoy convencido que es un error en como están anidados los bucles, pero no salgo de ahí...

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde entendí, necesitas devolver los `<img>` para cada producto.

Esta estuctura debería funcionar si este es el caso:

```php
$raw_products = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products");

while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($raw_products)) {

  $product_images_tags = ''; // Inicializamos el contenedor de las etiquetas de las imagenes del producto

  $directory_url = ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "products" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $product['name']; // Seteamos el PATH del directorio

  if (file_exists($directory_url)) { // Verifica que el directorio exista
    $files = scandir($$directory_url); // Obtenemos un arreglo de los archivos del direcotorio

    foreach ($files as $file) { // Especificamos la iteración para el o los archivos del producto
      if (is_file($directory_url . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $file) && substr($item, 0 , 1) !== '.') { // Verificamos que el archivo corresponda a un archivo regular y que no esté oculto
        $picture_tag = '<img width="150px" src="' . $directory_url . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file . '">'; // Generamos la etiqueta
        $product_images_tags .= $picture_tag; // Adjuntamos el string a nuestro contenedor
      }
    }

  }

  print('<div>
          <div class="linia">
            '. $product['id'] .'
          </div>
          <div class="linia">
            '. $product['name'] .'
          </div>
          <div class="linia">
            '. $product['descripcion'] .'
          </div>
          <div class="linia">
            '. $product['pricem'] .'
          </div>
          '. $product_images_tags .'
        </div>');
}
```

En el caso de rescatar el primer archivo encontrado, puedes almacenar el nombre utilizando un criterio automático:

```php
$first_file_set = false;
$first_file = null;

foreach ($files as $file) { // Especificamos la iteración para el o los archivos del producto
  if (is_file($directory_url . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $file) && substr($item, 0 , 1) !== '.') { // Verificamos que el archivo corresponda a un archivo regular y que no esté oculto
    $picture_tag = '<img width="150px" src="' . $directory_url . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file . '">'; // Generamos la etiqueta
    if (!$first_file_set) {
      $first_file = $picture_tag; // Aquí rescatarías el primer archivo listado
      $first_file_set = true;
    }

    $product_images_tags .= $picture_tag; // Adjuntamos el string a nuestro contenedor
  }
}
```

También puedes rescatarlo validando que el primer archivo esté simplemente seteado:

```php
$first_file = null;

foreach ($files as $file) { // Especificamos la iteración para el o los archivos del producto
  if (is_file($directory_url . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $file) && substr($item, 0 , 1) !== '.') { // Verificamos que el archivo corresponda a un archivo regular y que no esté oculto
    $picture_tag = '<img width="150px" src="' . $directory_url . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file . '">'; // Generamos la etiqueta
    $first_file = $first_file ?: $picture_tag;
    $product_images_tags .= $picture_tag; // Adjuntamos el string a nuestro contenedor
  }
}
```

Otra forma, es hacerlo con un identificador en el nombre:

```php
$first_file = null;

foreach ($files as $file) { // Especificamos la iteración para el o los archivos del producto
  if (is_file($directory_url . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $file) && substr($item, 0 , 1) !== '.') { // Verificamos que el archivo corresponda a un archivo regular y que no esté oculto
    $picture_tag = '<img width="150px" src="' . $directory_url . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file . '">'; // Generamos la etiqueta
    if (str_contains($picture_tag, 'criterio')) { // Lo validas según contenido del texto del nombre
      $first_file = $picture_tag; // Aquí rescatarías el primer archivo.
    }
    $product_images_tags .= $picture_tag; // Adjuntamos el string a nuestro contenedor
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola,
Ante todo, gracias!

El codigo que pasasté, esta estupendo,  me muestra y soluciona un problemilla que tendré en el siguiente paso, así que repito, gracias porque me has ahorrado unas horitas de quebradero de cabeza.

Para este caso, lo que necesito es poner la primera de las imagenes que recoge, solo 1.
También me doy cuenta, que lo puedo solucionar si al subir el archivo lo renombro con una Z, pues será el ultimo en ser recogido, en teoria.

Creo que mi error, y batalla, es usar readdir() en lugar de scandir[], no?

Comment: Genial. Mira en el foreach de los archivos, puedes hacer tus validaciones según convengas. Puedes interrumpir la primera iteración o validarlo con un contador. Depende del criterio que uses como "primera imagen". Ahora, sobre si usar scandir o readdir, realmente no es un error. Yo utilicé scandir debido al hecho de que es eficiente de manera equilibrada entre sistemas operativos. Pero si usas Linux, sería recomendable readdir, debido a que suele ejecutarse un poco más rápido que scandir

Comment: Puedes revisar [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692764/readdir-vs-scandir) (en inglés) donde se evalúa la eficiencia de los distintos métodos.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda. he estado haciendo, o probando, validaciones en el foreach, la verdad es que trabajar con foreach no se me da demasiado bien, me costumbre en su dia con los While, y ahora hace algún tiempo que lo he tenido todo abandonado. Por otro lado, sobre el tema que me generó la pregunta, creo que aunque seguiré probando por cabezoneria y conocimiento, lo más sensato será que la foto que quiera usar, esa sí la meta en DB (el link), porque es dificil controlar las subidas y recogidas del Directorio, y si lo usa un tercero será complicado de tener resultados deseados.